# Set adds callback from useCallback two times

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, set

Set from another file adds callback from `useCallback` two times:

**test.ts:**

```
export const testSet = new Set();
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { testSet } from "./test.ts";

export default function App() {
  const callback = useCallback(() => {}, []);

  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  testSet.add(callback);

  console.log(testSet);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setState((prev) => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        Update state
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

***Link to sandbox***: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/epic-platform-h22jql?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrgejbev0006356kslf25th9%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrgejbes0002356k29rh1wp9%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrgejbet0003356kyxleqcil%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrgejbet0005356k3bimqnhh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clrgejbes0002356k29rh1wp9%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrgejbes0002356k29rh1wp9%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clrgejbet0005356k3bimqnhh%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrgejbet0004356k5nayyaf4%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrgejbet0005356k3bimqnhh%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clrgejbet0004356k5nayyaf4%2522%257D%252C%2522clrgejbet0003356kyxleqcil%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clrgejbet0003356kyxleqcil%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Set adds callback from useCallback two times, so `testSet` has two functions. Also if I update the state of App component, `testSet` preserves only 2 functions.

Why does it add function second time, if useCallback memoizes callback, so `testSet` should not add function second time because it is the same function?

If I  disable `StrictMode`, it works how it should (not adding function second time).

Why does it work that way and how to fix that?